# SQL ORDER BY one of two column values with value used from first column if not null and other column if first column is null

Tags: sql

I need an ORDER BY in my sql statement that will sort based on the value from the first column, if it's not null, and the value from the second column if the first column value is null.

It would do something like:

```
Select firstColumn, secondColumn 
from myTable 
order by if(firstColumn!=null) then firstColumn else secondColumn
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `COALESCE` in the `ORDER BY` clause to implement the logic you want:

```
SELECT firstColumn, secondColumn
FROM myTable
ORDER BY COALESCE(firstColumn, secondColumn);
```

By definition, `COALESCE(firstColumn, secondColumn)` will return the first column if not `NULL`, and otherwise fall back and return the second column.

Comment: Agree, this will be better then using 'case-when' for this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case-when` statement:

```
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN firstcolumn IS NOT NULL THEN firstcolumn 
    ELSE secondcolumn 
END
```